# How to make php curl_exec listen to server for long

Tags: php, curl

I am Sorry if my title is not clear. But let me explain my problem. We are developing a Web application where a User enters a Code from web and web sends and SMS to his/her phone. This User has upto 120 second to respond to this SMS.

We are using `curl_exec()` to call an online API to initial SMS to users phone and give us feedback.But our curl request runs for about 40seconds and goes to Internal Server Error.Now if this User use less than 40 second to response it works and we recieve feedback But if user uses more than 40seconds it send the response to API but before API response to us our Application has already runs to Internal Server Error (500 Error code).

```
$header = array(
                  "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                  "Accept: text/xml",
                  "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                  "Pragma: no-cache",
                  "Content-length: ".strlen($send),
                );

            $URL = 'https://IP:port/API_REQUEST_URL';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); //array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $send );

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
             $result = curl_exec($ch); 
             echo $result;
             curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem relies in the server configuration, you should check your php.init for the following entries:

```
set_time_limit
max_execution_time
```

And also check your logs for memory heaps and check if the configuration of the memory limit on your server is accurate.
I'm guessing that your php is dying either by memory limit or by time limit in your php.ini configuration file.

Comment: @axicala. i have use set_time_limit(120); but it still goes to Internal Server Error. Also i dont think it is Memory cause when the user uses < 40 seconds it work. why??? :(

Comment: Check your error.log, there you will get what is causing the 500

Comment: i am using Laravel, laravel.log shows no error. where can i see this error.log you are talking about?

Comment: depends on your php setting, usually (Linux) /var/log/php5/error.log

Comment: cant still fine any related issue in log. may be i am looking at the wrong log usr/local/apache/logs/error_log